# Python IDLE not starting when clicking .py files in OSX Finder

Tags: macos, python, osx-mountain-lion, finder

I can open IDLE.

After opening IDLE, I can do `File > Open > some_file.py` just fine.

When IDLE is open, I can also just double-click on any `.py` files in Finder and they will open in IDLE.

From the Terminal, whether IDLE is already open or not, I can type `idle -e some_file.py` and open a `.py` file just fine that way.

However, when IDLE is *not* already open, if I double-click on `.py` files in Finder, nothing happens.  If I `right-click > Open with > IDLE` in Finder, nothing happens.  For some reason, it appears I cannot launch IDLE by opening `.py` files in Finder.

I'm using OSX 10.8.2, Python 2.7.3.  Any ideas?

Comment: That's because it assumes you're wanting to run the script instead of edit it.

Answer (score 0):

> However, when IDLE is not already open, if I double-click on .py files in Finder, nothing happens.

That's probably not true.  The default action of any `.py` file is to run it as a script.  That's the same for any machine (linux, mac, windows).  You'll need to change it's default action by following [these instructions](http://www.fileinfo.com/help/mac_change_program):

1. Right click file
2. Select "Get Info"
3. Change the default "Open With" Application to IDLE

Note: By doing this, if you have any scripts that you want to run by double clicking on them, you'll no longer be able to do so.

Comment: This is not the issue. As I mentioned in the OP, when IDLE is open, I can just double-click on any `.py` files in Finder and they will open in IDLE.  Also if I right-click on a `.py` file and go to "Open with", the default is IDLE.  Also if I follow your instructions the default "Open with" application is already set to IDLE.